# How to disable timeout in jQuery and CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

My `CasperJS` script calls via `jQuery` an `PHP script`. Problem is, that the PHP script takes around 70 sec to excute, but somehow CasperJS or jQuery are canceling the request after around 30 sec and throw the error: `Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101`.

Code to call the PHP script:

```
var result = casper.evaluate(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({'async':false});
    var result = $.get('http://localhost/full.php', function() {} );
    return result;
});
```

I tried the following solutions:

```
// For CasperJS:
pageSettings: {
    timeout: 999999999
}

// For jQuery
$.ajaxSetup({'timeout':999999999});
```

Also I made sure that the executed PHP script is not the cause for the error (I made a test-script with all used functions, which only takes some seconds to execute. This works fine).

I read that jQuery has no timeout by default and that CasperJS throws an error, when a timeout occurs. But somehow it must be timeout error, because it always occurs after around 30 sec. (btw.. the PHP script uses `set_time_limit(0);`)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

> Also I made sure that the executed PHP script is not the cause for the
>   error (I made a test-script with all used functions, which only takes
>   some seconds to execute. This works fine).

It's maybe the problem. Did you tried when you script when it takes 70 s ? Php has also a maximum execution time setting as said [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). By default, it's 30 secs. Try to test in the same scenario.

Jsut for futures references, the default Jquery Ajax Timeout is 0 (technically it's undefined, but behaves as 0). This means no timeout in jQuery itself... You could specify one via `$.ajax ({timeout: XXXX })` or `$.ajaxSetup ({timeout: XXXX })`. The complete callback contains a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

There is also two timeouts in casperJs : [timeout and steptimeout](http://casperjs.org/api.html#intro). There are also two callback `ontimeout` and on `steptimout` that are executed when script/step execution time exceeds these limits.